# How to pass a directory path containing spaces to the -C option of tar in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, tar

i'm building up in a bash script a tar command like this:

```
/usr/bin/tar -cvjf /tmp/archive.tar.bz2  -X excl.txt -C '/cygdrive/c/Users/Utente/dir with spaces/' dir1 dir2 dir2
```

/usr/bin/tar: '/cygdrive/c/Users/Utente/dir: Cannot open: No such file or directory

if i test the command in the shell it works fine.

if i run the script the script complains. i think that something fails when tar tries to change directory.

of course i can change directory in the script an then avoid the use of the -C option but i miss the opportunity to use the -X option.

Comment: In the script, with the actual path, does it contain any variables that are expanded?

Comment: Please, post your script.

Comment: yes. I had: TARCMD = <some weired varibales with everything in>. my mistake was that I invoked simply: $TARCMD in the script. the solution was simple: eval $TARCMD. of course without space it works but with spaces the shell stops at the space. thanks.